# Streamlit is not Recognising my Python File post deployment

Tags: python, python-3.x, deployment, streamlit

I have created a Streamlit app which runs fine on my local with command streamlit run app.py, however when i am trying to host it on streamlit i am getting following error:

```
[06:08:51]  Processed dependencies!

Usage: streamlit run [OPTIONS] TARGET [ARGS]...

Try 'streamlit run --help' for help.


Error: Streamlit requires raw Python (.py) files, but the provided file has no extension.

For more information, please see https://docs.streamlit.io

[06:08:52] ❗️ error restarting streamlit: exit status 7: output: streamlit: ERROR (not running)
streamlit: ERROR (spawn error)

[06:08:52] ❗️ Error during processing dependencies! Please fix the error and push an update, or try restarting the app.

Usage: streamlit run [OPTIONS] TARGET [ARGS]...

Try 'streamlit run --help' for help.


Error: Streamlit requires raw Python (.py) files, but the provided file has no extension.

For more information, please see https://docs.streamlit.io

Usage: streamlit run [OPTIONS] TARGET [ARGS]...

Try 'streamlit run --help' for help.


Error: Streamlit requires raw Python (.py) files, but the provided file has no extension.

For more information, please see https://docs.streamlit.io

Usage: streamlit run [OPTIONS] TARGET [ARGS]...

Try 'streamlit run --help' for help.


Error: Streamlit requires raw Python (.py) files, but the provided file has no extension.

For more information, please see https://docs.streamlit.io

[06:10:24] ❗️ Streamlit server consistently failed status checks

[06:10:24] ❗️ Please fix the errors, push an update to the git repo, or reboot the app.
```

This is my repository structure

Wanted to deploy the app on streamlit but received error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file you're trying to deploy from doesn't have the `.py` file extension. Streamlit Community Cloud requires a `.py` file in order to deploy your app.